# Different colors even though RGB values are equal

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, colors, interface-builder

I'm facing a quite weird color issue with the Interface Builder in Xcode.

I've set the background of my view in my view controller to `#1F242C`:

[image: view controller's view background]

So far so good.
Then I create a UITableViewCell in a nib file where I set the background to the exact same color `#1F242C`:

[image: table view cell view background]

Now when I start the app, the background of the UITableViewCell is suddenly different from the viewcontroller view's background, even though the RGB values match and the opacity too.

When I analyze a screenshot with Photoshop

The view's background is: `#29303A`

and the cell's background is: `#1F242C`

Whey are they different colors despite the RGB values being the same? I don't change the colors programmatically in my source code.

Here's how the different colors look:

[image]

Comment: In your debug view heirarchy, can you check the views that are made? Are the colors still different and on the views you expect them to be on? Could it be that there is a view overlapping them causing this issue?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the view with the different colors?

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of the view

Comment: Since the background colour of both the tableView and the cell is the same maybe you should try using clear colour for cell's background. Once this happened to me too but I couldn't find the reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an issue due to iOS 10 and the new extended color gamut of the new devices screens.

Click on the wheel at the right of "RGB slider" in your color picker, and chose sRGB IEC61966 2-1.

You will see that the  RGB values will change at this point. Put them back to the RGB values you previously entered. That should be it!

[image: color gamut]

Comment: is this an issue that only arises if setting colors directly in the storyboard? What's the situation regarding setting colors programmatically?

Comment: @Essenceofchicken Yes the issue comes from the storyboard. In the latest Xcode you have to change this parameter in order to match the UIColor created programatically (which doesn't change in the latest version).